# Change Identity Id from string to int

Tags: c#, .net, identity

I tried to change the Id from string to int but I encountered a problem :
All the other posts have used in _Startup file  :

```
    services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole<int>>.()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext,int>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

but when I try to do the same I get this error when I add int after DatabaseContext :

> 'IdentityBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddEntityFrameworkStores' and no extension method 'AddEntityFrameworkStores' accepting a first argument of type 'IdentityBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (Presentation)

The other changes that I did :

```
       public class User : IdentityUser <int>  

       public class DatabaseContext :IdentityDbContext <User,IdentityRole<int>,int>                     

       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)

       {

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(i => {
            i.ToTable("Users");
            i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>(i => {
            i.ToTable("Role");
            i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>(i => {
            i.ToTable("UserRole");
            i.HasKey(x => new { x.RoleId, x.UserId });
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<int>>(i => {
            i.ToTable("UserLogin");
            i.HasKey(x => new { x.ProviderKey, x.LoginProvider });
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<int>>(i => {
            i.ToTable("RoleClaims");
            i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<int>>(i => {
            i.ToTable("UserClaims");
            i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        });
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

}
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: I was trying to delete my post but I don't find any delete button

Comment: @CalvT븃 Not entirely true; _Users can delete their own questions if the question: has zero answers OR only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes... Simply click the delete link underneath the question._ [Help/Deleted Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

Comment: Ok ; Thank you and sorry

Comment: @CalvT븃 Nope, just the one, currently 0 votes. More likely david didn't notice the subtle "delete" link under the question.

Comment: Yes I didn't see it

Comment: I will keep it ; You can up-vote it

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you are using `ASP.NET Core 2.x` which is no longer accepting generic `TKey` argument.

> The AddEntityFrameworkStores method doesn't accept a TKey argument as
>   it did in ASP.NET Core 1.x. The primary key's data type is inferred by
>   analyzing the DbContext object.

Related links:

[Configure the ASP.NET Core Identity primary key data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-primary-key-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x)